# LSB of ARM7TDMI link register on external interrupt (IRQ) call from Thumb mode

Tags: arm, irq, arm7

Assuming that the ARM7TDMI is in Thumb mode when an interrupt occurs, is the LSB of r14_irq = 1 once the ISR is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Mostly because an exception return is a very different thing from a branch - it doesn't interwork to Thumb state in the same way as a branch does, because it's *replacing the entire execution state anyway* by virtue of restoring the SPSR. Specifically, the instruction set state of the interrupted context is encoded in the SPSR.T bit.

Comment: Then, why would a BL in Thumb mode itself set the LSB of LR to 1. Isn't the mode (Thumb) is specified in the T bit of the CPSR making the 1 in the LR redundant?

Comment: @rvt Because the callee function is going to `bx lr`.